# "mkdir()" not working

Tags: c, copy, mkdir, subdirectory

Hi I am trying to create a recurive copy function that emulates the CP program in unix. So basically if i run the program with -r option it will copy a folder with all of it's sub directories. I am using the folling function.

```
void copyDirectory(char *destDir, char *dirName)
{
    printf("copyDirectory run \n");

    int charCnt;
    int srcFd;
    int dstFd;
    char* sourcePath;
    char* destPath;

    DIR *dir = opendir(dirName);
    if(dir == NULL){
        return;
    }

    char Path[256], *EndPtr = Path;

    struct dirent *e;
    strcpy(Path, dirName);

    EndPtr += (strlen(dirName)+1);
    while((e = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        sourcePath = malloc(strlen(Path)+1+strlen(e->d_name));
        destPath = malloc(strlen(destDir)+1+strlen(Path));
        strcpy(destPath, destDir);
        strcat(destPath, slash);
        strcat(destPath, Path);

        if (0 != access(destPath, F_OK)) {
            mkdir(destPath,0777);
            printf("mkdir %s \n", destPath);
        }

        strcpy(sourcePath, Path);
        strcat(sourcePath, slash);
        strcat(sourcePath, e->d_name);

        printf("copyDirectory destPath = %s \n", destPath);
        printf("copyDirectory sourcePath = %s \n", sourcePath);

        if(strcmp(e->d_name, dott) == 0){
            continue;
        }
        if(strcmp(e->d_name, dot) == 0){
            continue;
        }


        if(whatType(sourcePath) == 1){
            copyDirectory(destDir, sourcePath);   
        }
        else{
            /* copyFile(destPath, sourcePath);*/
        } 

        free(sourcePath);
        free(destPath);
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine if i run the program using the following command line.

```
Mycopy Sourcefolder/ DestinationFoler/
```

but when I run it with this command line, the mkdir function inside my program stops working.

```
Mycopy Sourcefolder/Subfolder/ DestinationFoler/
```

The weird thing is I put a printf marker inside the mkdir call to see what destPath was and the formatting looks no different to when I call the program not using a subfoler. What is going on?

Comment: If only there was a way to test the return result of `mkdir` that would give you a hint as to why it is failing....

Comment: @Duck means test the return code, check errno to see why it fails. +1 for sarcasm.  But you never know when a poster here will not get humor like that, due to different backgounds....

Comment: @jim mcnamara - you are right about different backgrounds which I am sometimes guilty of overlooking but I wasn't aiming at sarcasm as much as "what's the next question I should be asking myself instead of running to Stackoverflow?"  Maybe I am getting petulant in my old age but the return code issue has become a pet peeve lately.  Why isn't this emphasized in schools and other programming sources more?

Comment: Actually I got the sarcarsm and has since tested with the error returns and found that my destPath is wrong. I need it to mkdir DestinationFolder/Subfolder,  not DestinationFolder/SourceFolder/SubFoloder. How do I do that? I tried putting strcat(destPath, basename(Path)); but that make it work if I only had one subdirectory but messes the directories up if I got deeper directory trees.

Answer (score 3):

It is always good practice to test the return value of functions and system calls like `mkdir`.  This would have find you the (possible) mistake in your code that I'm explaining below.

```
if (0 != mkdir(destPath,0777)) {
  printf("When executing: mkdir(\"%s\")\n", destPath);
  perror("mkdir");
  exit(1);
}
```

With this you would see:

```
When executing: mkdir("trg/src")
mkdir: No such file or directory
```

---

Your code seems to be working OK.  To test it, I had to add a few `#include`'s and `#define`'s and to implement function `whatType`, so everything I'm writing presupposes that we have similar definitions for these.

There is a big difference between your code and `cp -r` in Linux, which could explain the problem you're witnessing.  Suppose you have an existing directory structure under `src/` and that **there is no directory** named `trg/`.  if you execute:

```
cp -r src trg
```

this will result in the complete directory structure `src/` being copied under `trg/`, that is, if you had a file `src/f`, this would be copied to `trg/f`.

On the other hand, if initially **there was a directory** named `trg`, then the complete directory structure `src/` would be copied under `trg/src/`, that is, the file `src/f` would be copied to `trg/src/f`.

With your code, the behavior is always the second.  Your code assumes that the target root directory exists: the first directory it tries to create is always `trg/src`.  This fails, if `trg/` does not already exist.

Comment: actually that is my goal. if directory exists it should make trg/src/file, but the issue i have is when I tried to copy src/subfolder/ to trg it should try to mkdir trg/subfolder, not trg/src/subfolder

Comment: Is there an easy way to just remove the first word from a string using / as a delineating character?

Comment: Function `strchr(s, c)` will find the first occurrence of character `c` in string `s` and return a pointer to that, or `NULL` if it does not exist.  That pointer plus one removes the first word.